# How do I transfer input and output for my function from the console to my GUI app?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm not sure how to transfer the input and output of my function from the console to the interface. I don't know if I should do the destroy function and create a new frame each time.

```
from tkinter import *

states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho",
          "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi",
          "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio",
          "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia",
          "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]
capitals = ["Montgomery", "Juneau", "Phoenix", "Little Rock", "Sacramento", "Denver", "Hartford", "Dover", "Tallahassee", "Atlanta", "Honolulu", "Boise",
            "Springfield", "Indianapolis", "Des Moines", "Topeka", "Frankfurt", "Baton Rouge", "Augusta", "Annapolis", "Boston", "Lansing", "St. Paul", "Jackson",
            "Jefferson City", "Helena", "Lincoln", "Carson City", "Concord", "Trenton", "Santa Fe", "Albany", "Raleigh", "Bismarck", "Columbus",
            "Oklahoma City", "Salem", "Harrisburg", "Providence", "Columbia", "Pierre", "Nashville", "Austin", "Salt Lake City", "Montpelier", "Richmond",
            "Olympia", "Charleston", "Madison", "Cheyenne"]

def geofunction():
    i = 0
    for element in states:
        value = 1
        while value == 1:
            test = input(element + ": ") 
            if test == capitals[i]:
                print("You got it!")
                value = 0
            else:
                print("Try again")
        i += 1
    print("Game Finished!")

root = Tk()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack()

theLabel = Label(topFrame, text = "Welcome to the Geography Quizzer!\nClick below to get started!")
theLabel.pack(fill=BOTH)

getstarted = Button(bottomFrame, text="Get started!", fg="black", bg="tan", command=geofunction)
getstarted.pack(fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to destroy your frame every time, you can change it. You can put a Label in tour frame and then change the text of the frame. For example, if you want to change the text of you `theLabel` you can do:

```
theLabel['text'] = 'new text'
root.update()
```

ad to use input, I believe you would prefer to change the input to an Entry Widget in the GUI. The Entry widget is a widget where the user can type the input and you can access it with an Entry.get() or using a tkinter variable as the Entry.textvariable, example:

```
from tkinter import *

states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho",
          "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi",
          "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio",
          "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia",
          "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]
capitals = ["Montgomery", "Juneau", "Phoenix", "Little Rock", "Sacramento", "Denver", "Hartford", "Dover", "Tallahassee", "Atlanta", "Honolulu", "Boise",
            "Springfield", "Indianapolis", "Des Moines", "Topeka", "Frankfurt", "Baton Rouge", "Augusta", "Annapolis", "Boston", "Lansing", "St. Paul", "Jackson",
            "Jefferson City", "Helena", "Lincoln", "Carson City", "Concord", "Trenton", "Santa Fe", "Albany", "Raleigh", "Bismarck", "Columbus",
            "Oklahoma City", "Salem", "Harrisburg", "Providence", "Columbia", "Pierre", "Nashville", "Austin", "Salt Lake City", "Montpelier", "Richmond",
            "Olympia", "Charleston", "Madison", "Cheyenne"]
counter = 0

root = Tk()

def geofunction():
    global counter

    def get_answer():
        global counter
        if input_entry.get() == capitals[counter]:
            theLabel['text'] = "You got it!"
            counter += 1
            input_text['text']=states[counter]+":"
        else:
            theLabel['text'] = "Try again"
        if counter == len(states):
            theLabel['text'] = "Game Finished!"
            input_entry.destroy()
    
    getstarted.pack_forget()
    input_text = Label(text=states[counter]+":")
    input_text.pack()
    input_entry = Entry()
    input_entry.pack()
    Button(text='answer', command=get_answer).pack()


topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack()

theLabel = Label(topFrame, text = "Welcome to the Geography Quizzer!\nClick below to get started!")
theLabel.pack(fill=BOTH)

getstarted = Button(bottomFrame, text="Get started!", fg="black", bg="tan", command=geofunction)
getstarted.pack(fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```